# Share std::fstream or std::stringstream trough std::iostream

Tags: c++, stream, c++03

I have a function that creates `std::stringstream` or `std::fstream` depending on condition, like:

```
// Some class, stringStream_ and fileStream_ are members
// obj.Stream() returns std::iostream&
if (condition)
{
    stringStream_.str(std::string());
    obj->Stream().rdbuf(stringStream.rdbuf());
}
else
{
    boost::filesystem::path temp = boost::filesystem::unique_path();
    fileStream_.open(temp.native().c_str(), std::ios_base::trunc | std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out);
    obj->Stream().rdbuf(fileStream_.rdbuf());
}
```

and then this `obj` object is processed in another thread, so at this moment the function above may be called once more and `streambuf` in `stringStream` will be reset and `fileStream_` will fail to open new file because it is associated with another one.

I can't make a function like `obj.SetStream()` because streams are non-copyable.

The question is: how can I create either `std::stringstream` or `std::fstream` and pass it to the object so the object becomes an owner of the stream (note object stores `std::iostream` because it doesn't know what type of stream will be passed).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass around a pointer (raw or smart) to dynamically allocated instance of either `std::fstream` or `std::stringstream` typed as pointer to `std::iostream`. The client of the stream then just needs to do something like `std::iostream & s = *iostreamPtr; s << "yay!";` to use it.

Comment: Is it legal to write something like `boost::shared_ptr<std::iostream> stream(new std::stringstream)`?

Comment: @maverik: Yes, it is, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

You could just make this into a templated function

```
template<class T>
void yourFunc(T& object) 
{
  if (typeid(T) == typeid(std::stringstream))
  {
    stringStream_.str(std::string());
    obj->Stream().rdbuf(stringStream.rdbuf());
  }
  else
  {
    boost::filesystem::path temp = boost::filesystem::unique_path();
    fileStream_.open(temp.native().c_str(), std::ios_base::trunc | std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out);
    obj->Stream().rdbuf(fileStream_.rdbuf());
  }
}
```

Comment: Either my explanation of the problem is bad or you don't understand the question. Thanks anyway