# Java: common interface to InputStream and OutputStream

Tags: java, stream

This question is related (in some way) with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715473/share-stdfstream-or-stdstringstream-trough-stdiostream).

Basically, I want to make a function, like this:

```
public InputOutputStream func()
{
    if (condition)
    {
        // open a file stream and convert to InputOutputStream 
    }
    else
    {
        // make an InputOutputStream from string
    }
}
```

Several questions arise:

- I can't find anywhere class like `InputOutputStream`. It's only `InputStream` and `OutputStream` and its variations (like `InputDataStream`, `OutputDataStream`, etc). Is there one? I need a stream which supports both read and write operations.
- How can I make an `InputOutputStream` from file?
- How can I make an `InputOutputStream` from string?

For C++ `InputOutputStream` is a `std::iostream`. And I can convert `std::fstream` or `std::stringstream` to it without any problems. Is it reachable in Java?

Thanks.

Comment: CHeck out: http://ostermiller.org/convert_java_outputstream_inputstream.html but I think it is more work than just using what you need based on a condition

Comment: If you want to read and write from a file, either use `RandomAccessFile`, or open an `InputStream`, read, close, and then open an `OutputStream`, write, and close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider using a RandomAccessFile instead.

Comment: Can't force myself to think like Java programmer. C++ still owns my brains. May be this could help. Thanks.

Comment: It's a rarely used class. I would be more inclined to review the requirement actually.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `InputOutputStream` in Java. If you want to DIY, follow the instructions below. If you extend an `abstract class`, use the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) to ensure you override *every* `abstract` method; there aren't that many.

Make a class that uses two streams, an `InputStream` and an `OutputStream`. Extend one of the classes; you can't inherit from both classes (the `Stream` classes are abstract).

Then, write each method of your `InputOutputStream` in a way that calls the appropriate `InputStream` or `OutputStream` method.

```
public InputOutputStream () {
    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(source);
    OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(source);
}
//....
public int read () { return is.read(); }
public void write (int x) { os.write(x); }
//....more methods....
// (if you extend an abstract class, you must override EVERY
// abstract method in the class...)
```

If needed, you could use an adapter class that wraps around an `InputOutputStream` and extends the other `Stream` class, passing all method calls through to the underlying `InputOutputStream`.

**However,** it's probably easier to just use raw `InputStream`s and `OutputStreams`, though, and just pass the needed one to whatever method or code uses it....

Hope this helped, anyway.